# Filter data in django admin inline create view

Tags: django, django-admin, django-inline-models

this is my first post here and im hoping to find a solution for my situation:

The thing is... I got a admin inline who show the relate info of a model. by this, i can see which contract_product belongs to current client.

When im creating a new object in the inline, aka click in the following button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA6mF.png)

I cant see a list of option as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToJMT.png)

The problem is... the client must see only their products, but here i see all products for all type of clients?

PS: product and client has a direct relationship.

Hope someone can understand my problem and helps me!

Theres a kt if thing i've tried far now, but nothing succesful to talk about

Comment: Can you please provide your current code for the admin inline

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033260/filtering-django-admin-inline-limit-the-choices-list you might add this and benfit from it

Comment: I think Ahmed is right in his approach - adding the `formfield_for_foreignkey()` method to your ClientContractInline class . The relevant docs can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey